# Error getting the list of sites from the target environment: An invalid dn syntax has been specified

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller, failover

Trying to add another (second) Domain Controller to an existing Domain. In the second step of "Active Directory Domain Services Configuration Wizard" getting the following error:

> Error getting the list of sites from the target environment: An
>   invalid dn syntax has been specified.

Due to the above error, the "Site name" dropdown is empty. Here is the [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/MMSOhZvx).

PS: Both the main Domain Controller (current one) and the one that I'm trying to add run on Windows Server 2012. The operation level of AC and Domain Control is also Windows Server 2012.

What is wrong?

Comment: The screen has a hyperlink to show "more information". What does that say when you expand it?

Comment: it displays exact same message but this time it is on a message box

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Primary DNS is set to an active, reachable DC.
See if you can ping your local domain name from the "new" server.
If not able to run:
ipconfig /flushdns
and then:
ipconfig /registerdns
Now try to ping local domain. If this works the sites should be retrievable.